# Como efetuar uma tabulação cruzada e ponderada?

Tags: r

Gostaria de fazer fazer uma tabulação cruzada porém com o `prop.table` não consigo utilizar a variável referente ao peso.

Utilizo o comando abaixo:

```
prop.table(table(mydata$Q_15,mydata$Q_35),1)
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Obtive o que desejava do seguinte modo:

Utilizei o `crosstab` e com o peso:

```
tabela <- crosstab(mydata$Q_15, mydata$Q_35, weight = mydata$PESO)
```

Selecionei apenas os valores absolutos

```
tabela <- tabela$t
```

Então, como um detalhe adicional, calculei a percentagem por linha e arredondei:

```
(tabela <- 100*round(prop.table(tabela, 1), 2))
```

#### Gostaria de outra alternativa.

Answer (score 2):

É possível obter através do `xtabs`:

```
dados <- data.frame(minusculas = sample(letters[1:5], 100, rep = TRUE),
MAIUSCULAS =  sample(LETTERS[1:5], 100, rep = TRUE),
peso <- rchisq(100, 10),
lucro <- rnorm(100, 0, 10))

with(dados, xtabs(peso ~ minusculas + MAIUSCULAS))
with(dados, xtabs(lucro ~ minusculas + MAIUSCULAS))
with(dados, xtabs(cbind(peso, lucro) ~ minusculas + MAIUSCULAS))
```

O `xtabs` faz a soma das variáveis a esquerda da fórmula pelos níveis das variáveis a direita, permitindo valores negativos (como é o caso da variável lucro).